# Why are the rows of images below being moved from above?

Tags: html, image

For some reason when hovering over a item the whole next row gets shifted down.

I output a look for as many items there are in the array, but I dont think that's important. I'm sure it's the HTML and CSS which is the issue. So, it creates a link then uses the PHP to get info on the link, then draws a div and has some heading text inside then ends the link.

From the CSS it sets a ratio of the image `padding-top`. I'm guessing the problem is with the positioning or the transformation, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
echo '<div class="column">';
$backdrop   = $results->poster_path;
if (empty($backdrop) && is_null($backdrop)){
    $backdrop =  '/images/no-gambar.jpg';
} else {
    $backdrop = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300'.$backdrop;
}
echo '<a href="movie.php?id=' . $id . '"><div class="imageFramed" 
style="background-image:url('.$backdrop.');">';

echo '<h4 class="centered">'.$title.'</h4></div></a>';

echo '</div>';
```

YouTube Example: [Here](https://youtu.be/UVPivVpe1Pc/).

And for the CSS:

```
.imageFramed {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 150%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 5%;
    max-width: 100%; 
    margin: 5%;
    transition: transform .2s;
}
.imageFramed:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.01); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.01); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: scale(1.03); 
}
.imageFramed::after {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0, #000000 100%);
    margin-top: -150px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    content: '';
    border-radius: 5%;
}

.colour-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
/*Title*/

.centered {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 25px; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the property *box-sizing: border-box*
In your css:

**Blockquote**

```
html {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Still doing exactly the same thing yet added html and body box sizings.